# 400 server error if to try to send http Get requests with params and cookies

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to send https requests with python "requests" lib

```
payLoad = {'session_id': str(webSessionId), 'Merchant': 'Company'}

resp =  requests.get(url, params = payLoad, cookies = cookiesSession, headers = headers)
print resp.url
```

But I'm getting server error 400. At the same time if to check url from sent request can see following:

```
https://url/error
```

Passed parameters are missing.
If to remove cookies following url is returned:

```
https://url?Merchant=Company&session_id=d1160eda748a5ede015bbe1abe35606138086fc8
```

But Server returns 403 error(authorization)
Cookies and headers are valid as were successfully used in previous two https request. But here is some strange situation. How can I send "get" request with params and cookies?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it displays "error" word instead of passed url parameters:
https://url/error

Comment: looks like need to find proper way of params passing. If to use json.dumps(params), parameters are added to url, but in wrong format